# Fix missing unicode symbol on safari/iOS

Tags: ios, css, safari

On my app, in safari and iOS I want to use the Atom Symbol, U+269B. On every other browser it appears correctly as just a symbol text like element. On Safari and in iOS it appears as more of an image.

[image: This is the image]

Is there a CSS trick I can use to make sure that it appears as normal text or should I change to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add U+FE0E after U+269B. "⚛" without, "⚛︎" with.

That suffix is a "font variation selector", if you want to read more about it. [This](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html) is the most thorough reference.